# log creation date in ISO format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ctime

I'm deleting some files from a folder and I want to log the file creation and deletion date in ISO format. I'm able to get the deletion date in ISO format but not the creation date in ISO format. Below is the command which I'm trying

`find /home/xyz/Pictures -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpeg" -type f -ctime +48 -printf "%P  %t $(date -Is)\n" >> log1.log`

Output:

`download.jpeg  Fri Apr 24 19:30:59.0130057090 2020 2020-11-01T16:12:57+05:30`

Required Output:

`download.jpeg  2020-04-24T11:12:57+05:30 2020-11-01T16:12:57+05:30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [`find` manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) readily reveals, the `printf` format code `%t` prints time in the locale's default format. You have to use `%T` with an additional format code character to get a different format.

Unfortunately, `find` doesn't have ISO format out of the box. `%T+` comes pretty close, but is not quite there. So you have to piece together multiple `%T` codes into the precise format you want.

`%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT`

Depending on your requirements, maybe also add `%TZ` to get the time zone.

Comment: `the Swedish and Japanese locales use ISO forma` Och wow, cool, so I wanted to test it,  [but the output did not change](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SatisfiedJampackedDecagons#main.sh). I opened [locale helper](https://lh.2xlibre.net/values/d_t_fmt/) and couldn't find it - for `sv_SE` it's `%a %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S`, no?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you're right - I'll just remove that part. I assume `repl.it` doesn't have those locales installed so then overriding `LC_TIME` is a no-op. (The site doesn't really work on mobile so I can't test.)

Comment: :/ I edited my /etc/locale.gen, did locale-gen, then tried - no difference